# Prism shell template, two instances of ShellView being created

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Started with a default [Prism Shell project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dphill/prism-quick-start-kit) and all was working as expected.

I began making changes and modifications and now the application is started twice.

`protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()`

The above override is only called once. The constructor(s) in the `ShellView` are being called twice. Once for the default constructor and once for a constructor taking an instance of the `ShellViewModel`.

Not sure what exactly is causing this however my hunch is that something was inadvertently modified and a trivial solution awaits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StartupUri` was set; my belief is that this happened when opening the solution with Expression Blend.